# Delete item from mongoDB from client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I've created a React app where you can post vinyls you have in your collection. Now I've implemented a button that is able to remove the selected item from the DOM but I also want the specific item to beremoved from the database. I'm using node with mongoose and that's (for now) my delete route:

```
vinylsRouter.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id

    Vinyl.findByIdAndDelete(id)
        .then((deletedVinyl) => {
            console.log(deletedVinyl)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
});
```

I also tried to store the id of the specific vinyl _id into a variable and then delete it. So I also created a get route to try to get the _id of the vinyl.

```
vinylsRouter.get('/:id', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Vinyl.findById(id, { __v: 0, updatedAt: 0, createdAt: 0 })
        .then((user) => {
            res.send(user)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        })
});
```

But now I don't know how to code in the client side to make that when an user clicks in the delete button, it sends something to get the id of the vinyl and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

First put some response when the delete works:

```
vinylsRouter.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id

    Vinyl.findByIdAndDelete(id)
        .then((deletedVinyl) => {
            res.status(200).send(deletedVinyl);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send(error);
        })
});
```

If are you trying to do a API You can use express/nodejs, and do `res.status(200).json({message: "my message"})`.

Second you can use a library like axios:

```
axios.delete(`http://localhost:xyz/vynils/`, { id })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react

And send for the server when the users click in the delete button.

You can use postman to test your delete endpoint before you use this on client-side (frontend), remember select delete in the dropbox and put a auth token (JWT) in the Authorization tab, or you can remove, only for test the auth middleware:

[image]

Say me if is this what you want to do.

Comment: I'm already using axios. But I don't know if the delete route that I'm using is ok. Cause now I don't know how to pass the id of the specific vinyl when clicking in the button of the item. If the delete route is fine I just need (in the client side) to tell the delete route the id of the specific vinyl to be deleted from the DB but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: For example:  You have a list of Items, you can get the id from this list, if you have a loop, you can create a trash button with this atribute `onclick="delete(vinyl.id)"`, or you can go to the specific page of your vinyl and send the ID (like a route parameter) and use the id on the delete function and call your endpoint using axios. One correction a put `axios.post`but is `axios.delete` another thing is you can test your backend with postman.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.delete('/product/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const query = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const result = await productCollection.deleteOne(query);
        res.send(result);
    })
```